# Excel, AVERAGE, SUBTRACT

Tags: microsoft-excel, average

In Excel;

I want to calculate an average of three values and to find a difference between result and a value in another column. I want the difference represented as a positive number.

```
R25 is -2.00;
R26 is -24.50;
R27 is -6.00;
H27 is 2820.00
```

My formula is;

```
=AVERAGE($R25,$R26,$R27)-$H27
```

or

```
=$H27-AVERAGE($R25,$R26,$R27)
```

in Excel I get -2830.30
With a calculator I get 2809.20

How can this be done?

Comment: *With a calculator I get 2809.20* It is wrong result. You do not count the signs. AVG = -10.8333333 (negative), so result = 2820 - (-10.8333333) = 2830.833333. PS. *in Excel I get -2830.30* is wrong too (misprint I think).

Answer (score 2):

The average of the three numbers is -10.8333..., whether you use a calculator or Excell.  But your two equations for taking the difference give, errr... different results:
Your first equation gives -10.83 - 2820.00 = -2830.83 
because subtracting a (positive) number from a negative number gives a negative number with greater absolute value.
Your second equation gives 2820.00 - (-10.83) = 2830.83
because subtracting a negative number is equivalent to adding a positive number.
Therefore, the equation you want is

```
=abs(AVERAGE($R25,$R26,$R27)-$H27)
```

or

```
=abs($H27-AVERAGE($R25,$R26,$R27))
```

which are equivalent to each other.
The =abs() function returns the absolute value of the argument, that is whatever is inside the ().

I suspect your mistake on the calculator came from ignoring the fact that the three values to be averaged were each negative values.  So your averaged them and got 10.83, then subtracted 10.83 from 2820.  The average of the three numbers is -10.83, not 10.83.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ABS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c) to get an absolute value of your subtraction result

> ***Description***
>
> Returns the absolute value of a number. The absolute value
> of a number is the number without its sign.

For your case it would be:

```
=ABS(AVERAGE($R25,$R26,$R27)-$H27)
```